# I cant post any data in my php script

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am working on an Android app but I am actually new at all this. I am trying to post some data to my database but I dont know whats going wrong with my code. I am using volley library to handle the requests and php/ mysql for back-end. 
I think the problem is with my php code because I am trying to save my data to table "social" that has a foreign key user_id reference to uid in table users. 
I dont know if I am explaining my problem right but below is my code. Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance

**function.php**

```
    public function storeSocial( $itemName, $email, $password, $URL,$note ){
    $em = $_SESSION['email'];
    $query = mysql_query("Select * from users where email = '$em'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($row)
    {
        $id = $row['uid'];
    }
    else return false;

    $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO social ( user_id, ItemName, email,     password, URL,note)
    VALUES( '$id','$itemName', '$email', '$password', '$URL', '$note')" );
    // check for successful store
    if ($res) {
       return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);
if ($tag == 'social')
{
    // Request type is Saving data
    $itemName = $_POST['ItemName'];
     $URL = $_POST['URL'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $note = $_POST['note'];

    $data = $db ->storeSocial($itemName, $email, $password, $URL, $note);
    // check for successful store
     if ($data)
    {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Failed to store";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

**SocialMedia_Info.java**

```
package com.appnucleus.passmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import helper.SQLiteHandler;
import helper.SessionManager;
import volley.AppController;
import volley.Config_URL;


public class SocialMedia_Info extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = SocialMedia_Info.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnSave;
private EditText inputURL;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private EditText inputNote;
private EditText inputItemName;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_socialmedia);


    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
    inputNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_note);
    inputURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_URL);
    inputItemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ItemName);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());


    // Save Button Click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String URL = inputURL.getText().toString();
            String note = inputNote.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            String ItemName = inputItemName.getText().toString();

            if(!validateEmail(email))
            {
                inputEmail.setError("Invalid Email");
                inputEmail.requestFocus();
            }
            else if(!validatePassword(password))
            {
                inputPassword.setError("Invalid Password");
                inputPassword.requestFocus();
            }
            else  if (( !ItemName.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() &&    !password.isEmpty() && !URL.isEmpty() && !note.isEmpty())
                    || ( !ItemName.isEmpty() || !email.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty() || !URL.isEmpty()))
            {
                saveData(ItemName,email,password, URL, note);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

}


        private boolean validateEmail(String vemail)
        {
            Pattern pattern;
            Matcher matcher;
            final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
            pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(vemail);

            return matcher.matches();

        }

        //at least one number
        //at least one upper case
        //at least one lowercase
        //at least one special chars
        //no white spaces
        //at least 6 chars
        private boolean validatePassword(String vpassword)
        {
            Pattern pattern;
            Matcher matcher;

            final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{6,}$";

            pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(vpassword);

            return  matcher.matches();

        }
        private void saveData( final String ItemName, final String email,            final String password, final String URL,
                                  final String note) {

            pDialog.setMessage("Saving Data ...");
            showDialog();

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    Config_URL.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Saving Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (!error) {

                            // Launch login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    SocialMedia_Info.this,
                                    Activity_SocialMedia.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                            // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                            // message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting params to register url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("tag", "social");
                    params.put("ItemName", ItemName);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("URL", URL);
                    params.put("note", note);
                    params.put("password", password);

                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
        }

        private void showDialog() {
            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
        }

        private void hideDialog() {
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: `I am trying to post some data to my database`. No you try to post some data to a php script. What the php script does with it comes after that. Now where do you have problems? First check if the sent data is received well by the script.

Comment: `where email = '$email'"`... I'm not too familiar with PHP, but I don't think that is how you concatenate strings

Comment: @greenapps well I dont seem to insert any data to my database.